# Split table column similar to nested table in html

Tags: tables

I want to put a row under the second and third columns of the first row. The content of the cell should be "ET in sec." and the content of the second cell should be "Memory in MB". The same for the third column. Is it possible? because the first value for each cell is the elapsed time separated by a hyphen and the second value is Memory in MB.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
    \hline
    Random AST depth & Static schedule evaluation & Demand evaluation ET in sec. \\ \hline
    & ET in sec. | Memory in MB & ET in sec. | Memory in MB \\ \hline
    1 & 0.009 - 2.971 & 0.091 - 5.536 \\ \hline
    2 & 0.003 - 2.921 & 0.009 - 3.178 \\ \hline
    3 & 0.005 - 3.646 & 0.009 - 4.037 \\ \hline
    4 & 0.019 - 7.872 & 0.019 - 9.548 \\ \hline
    5 & 0.097 - 13.091 & 0.123 - 21.288 \\ \hline
    6 & 0.044 - 46.332 & 0.053 - 86.475 \\ \hline
    7 & 0.064 - 57.778 & 0.122 - 112.154 \\ \hline
    8 & 0.501 - 155.338 & 0.761 - 453.930 \\ \hline
    9 & 4.029 - 198.215 & 2.276 - 866.845 \\ \hline
    10 & 7.439 - 1346.093 & 9.757 - 1652.442 \\ \hline
    11 & 30.57 - 1368.750 & 43.098 - 1915.167 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give a final display effect. I'm not sure what effect you want. I helped you achieve one according to my guess. You can see if it meets your requirements.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{title}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec      = {X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]},
cell{1}{2,4} = {c=2}{},
cell{1}{1}   = {r=2}{},
hlines,
vlines,
}
Random AST depth & Static schedule evaluation &              & Demand evaluation ET in sec. &              \\
                 & ET in sec.                 & Memory in MB & ET in sec.                   & Memory in MB \\
1                & 0.009                      & 2.971        & 0.091                        & 5.536        \\
2                & 0.003                      & 2.921        & 0.009                        & 3.178        \\
3                & 0.005                      & 3.646        & 0.009                        & 4.037        \\
4                & 0.019                      & 7.872        & 0.019                        & 9.548        \\
5                & 0.097                      & 13.091       & 0.123                        & 21.288       \\
6                & 0.044                      & 46.332       & 0.053                        & 86.475       \\
7                & 0.064                      & 57.778       & 0.122                        & 112.154      \\
8                & 0.501                      & 155.338      & 0.761                        & 453.930      \\
9                & 4.029                      & 198.215      & 2.276                        & 866.845      \\
10               & 7.439                      & 1346.093     & 9.757                        & 1652.442     \\
11               & 30.57                      & 1368.750     & 43.098                       & 1915.167     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{title}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec       = {Q[co=1,c,m]*{4}{Q[co=1,si={table-format=4.3},c,m]}},
cell{1}{2,4}  = {c=2}{},
cell{1}{1}    = {r=2}{},
hline{1,Z}    = {wd=.08em},
hline{2}      = {2-Z}{wd=.05em},
hline{3}      = {wd=.05em},
row{odd[3-Z]} = {bg=gray9!50},
column{1}     = {guard},
row{1-2}      = {guard},
}
Random AST depth & Static schedule evaluation &              & Demand evaluation ET in sec. &              \\
                 & ET in sec.                 & Memory in MB & ET in sec.                   & Memory in MB \\
1                & 0.009                      & 2.971        & 0.091                        & 5.536        \\
2                & 0.003                      & 2.921        & 0.009                        & 3.178        \\
3                & 0.005                      & 3.646        & 0.009                        & 4.037        \\
4                & 0.019                      & 7.872        & 0.019                        & 9.548        \\
5                & 0.097                      & 13.091       & 0.123                        & 21.288       \\
6                & 0.044                      & 46.332       & 0.053                        & 86.475       \\
7                & 0.064                      & 57.778       & 0.122                        & 112.154      \\
8                & 0.501                      & 155.338      & 0.761                        & 453.930      \\
9                & 4.029                      & 198.215      & 2.276                        & 866.845      \\
10               & 7.439                      & 1346.093     & 9.757                        & 1652.442     \\
11               & 30.57                      & 1368.750     & 43.098                       & 1915.167     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hyphens would be distracting and prevent alignment of the figures. Here are two suggestions; in both, vertical rules are omitted because useless and harmful to reading.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=2.3]
@{\hspace{3\tabcolsep}}
  S[table-format=4.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=4.3]
  @{}
} 
\toprule
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Random \\ AST depth \end{tabular}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Static schedule evaluation} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Demand evaluation} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& {ET (s)} & {Memory (MB)} & {ET (s)} & {Memory (MB)} \\
\midrule
1 & 0.009 & 2.971 & 0.091 & 5.536 \\
2 & 0.003 & 2.921 & 0.009 & 3.178 \\
3 & 0.005 & 3.646 & 0.009 & 4.037 \\
4 & 0.019 & 7.872 & 0.019 & 9.548 \\
5 & 0.097 & 13.091 & 0.123 & 21.288 \\
6 & 0.044 & 46.332 & 0.053 & 86.475 \\
7 & 0.064 & 57.778 & 0.122 & 112.154 \\
8 & 0.501 & 155.338 & 0.761 & 453.930 \\
9 & 4.029 & 198.215 & 2.276 & 866.845 \\
10 & 7.439 & 1346.093 & 9.757 & 1652.442 \\
11 & 30.57 & 1368.750 & 43.098 & 1915.167 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=4.3]
  S[table-format=2.3]
  S[table-format=4.3]
  @{}
} 
\toprule
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} Random \\ AST \\ depth \end{tabular}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Evaluation} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-5}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Static schedule} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Demand} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& {ET} & {Memory} & {ET} & {Memory} \\
\midrule
1 & 0.009 & 2.971 & 0.091 & 5.536 \\
2 & 0.003 & 2.921 & 0.009 & 3.178 \\
3 & 0.005 & 3.646 & 0.009 & 4.037 \\
4 & 0.019 & 7.872 & 0.019 & 9.548 \\
5 & 0.097 & 13.091 & 0.123 & 21.288 \\
6 & 0.044 & 46.332 & 0.053 & 86.475 \\
7 & 0.064 & 57.778 & 0.122 & 112.154 \\
8 & 0.501 & 155.338 & 0.761 & 453.930 \\
9 & 4.029 & 198.215 & 2.276 & 866.845 \\
10 & 7.439 & 1346.093 & 9.757 & 1652.442 \\
11 & 30.57 & 1368.750 & 43.098 & 1915.167 \\ 
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{ET in seconds, Memory in MB}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]